# Bootstrap Table not appearing correctly

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I am using JavaScript to loop through some data and build a number of tables and am using Bootstrap with the class table table-hover. This works absolutely fine on all tables except the very last table to be produced. The bottom table is always sqashed and the hover over doesn't work. The columns resize to the correct size but that's about it.

[image: Top table working correctly bottom table squashed and hover over not working]

I can't work it out, both tables have the class declared:

[image: Table HTML]

No matter how many tables are made it always happens on the very last table. I should point out that I've tried everything I can think of including adding a dummy table within the loop and the last interation but then that makes two squashed tables then.

Update: http://jsfiddle.net/si828/1ksyces5/8/

Code:

```
$('#tableContainer').empty();
    var div = document.getElementById('tableContainer');

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {

        div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML;

        var para = document.createElement("p");
        var logo = document.createElement("a");
        logo.setAttribute('class', 'glyphicon glyphicon-user');
        para.appendChild(logo);
        var node = document.createTextNode(" " + data[i].userName +  "  (" + data[i].userID + ") " );
        para.appendChild(node);

        var aTag = document.createElement("a");
        aTag.setAttribute('data-id-proxy' , data[i].userID);
        aTag.setAttribute('class' , 'open-AddUserModal');
        aTag.setAttribute('href' ,'#addUserModal');

        var span = document.createElement("span");
        span.setAttribute('class', 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus');
        aTag.appendChild(span);

        para.appendChild(node);
        para.appendChild(aTag);
        para.setAttribute('class', 'text-primary');
        div.appendChild(para);

        var table = document.createElement('table'), tr, td, row, cell;
        table.setAttribute('class', 'table table-hover');
        table.setAttribute('id', 'table' + data[i].userID);
        table.setAttribute('border', '1');

        var header = table.createTHead();
        var row = header.insertRow(0);

        var cell = row.insertCell(0);
        cell.setAttribute('style' , 'width: 20%');
        cell.style.backgroundColor = '#eee';
        cell.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
        cell.innerHTML = "SRM";

        var cell = row.insertCell(1);
        cell.setAttribute('style' , 'width: 13%');
        cell.style.backgroundColor = '#eee';
        cell.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
        cell.innerHTML = "Target User";

        var cell = row.insertCell(2);
        cell.setAttribute('style' , 'width: 20%');
        cell.style.backgroundColor = '#eee';
        cell.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
        cell.innerHTML = "Target User Name";

        for (row = 0; row < data[i].targetUsers.length; row++) 
        {
            tr = document.createElement('tr');
            td = document.createElement('td');
            tr.appendChild(td);
            td.innerHTML = data[i].targetUsers[row].srm;
            table.appendChild(tr);

            td = document.createElement('td');
            tr.appendChild(td);
            td.innerHTML = data[i].targetUsers[row].targetUser;

            td = document.createElement('td');
            tr.appendChild(td);
            td.innerHTML = data[i].targetUsers[row].targetUserName;


        }

    document.getElementById('tableContainer').appendChild(table);
    }
```

Comment: some code on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would definitely help. If this is a javascript problem we have no way to help you since you did not show any.

Comment: Sorry it was just on the way: http://jsfiddle.net/si828/1ksyces5/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/si828/1ksyces5/8/), your `div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML;` on line `10` should be the last statement of your outer for loop (on line `76`). Otherwise your table doesn't get a `<tbody>`, causing bootstrap to malfunction.

Here is the fixed one: http://jsfiddle.net/wsLzk5wq/

Comment: Absolute genius thank you SO much that took hours out of my life and it looks so simple now. I am confused about why I even need that line as it used to do something else but I realised that if I took it out none of the tables get a tbody, any ideas what it's doing because on paper it's just well doing nothing: div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML;

Answer (score 0):

If it is only the last table you could add custom css for the last table element by using a child selector.

E.g

HTML:

```
<div class="parent-container">
   <table>
     .......
   </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent-container table:last-child {
   padding: 10px !important;
   .......
}
```